# Start evil mode in insert for some buffers

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I would like to set some buffers to be opened in insert mode in evil.

For example in read-only buffers there is no point in having a normal mode since i then can't use q to exit but i have to do i q. This is annoying for interactive modes that produce error buffers.

What I have been trying and failed with is as follows:

```
(evil-set-initial-state view-mode 'insert)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the variable `evil-insert-state-modes`, which holds a list of modes that should be started in insert state:

```
(add-to-list 'evil-insert-state-modes 'view-mode)
```

There are analogous variables for emacs state, normal state, etc.

Comment: Looks like it is not view-mode I'm looking for, the buffer has the major mode Error, what mode would that be?