# how to map `q:i` on evil-mode

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I have a problem of mapping `q:i` on normal-mode, what i want is to open the ex-command-window and go to the insert mode.

this is my solution, but it will only open the command window without going to the insert mode:

```
(evil-define-command evil-command-window-ex-and-insert ()
  (evil-command-window-ex)
  (evil-insert)
)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd ";")  'evil-command-window-ex-and-insert)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `evil-command-window-mode` to the `evil-insert-state-modes` variable. The `evil-*-state-modes` variables dictate which states given major/minor modes start up in.

You can accomplish this with: `(add-to-list 'evil-insert-state-modes 'evil-command-window-mode)`.

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547567/start-evil-mode-in-insert-for-some-buffers).